# How to cite cirq in a scientific article?

Tags: cirq

What would be the best/prefered bibtex entry for citing cirq ?
Is this ok ?

```
@article{cirq,
    title={Cirq, a python framework for creating, editing, and invoking Noisy Intermediate Scale Quantum (NISQ) circuits},
    note={\url{https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq}}
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cirq has now a DOI published through Zenodo - please refer to https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq#how-to-cite-cirq for citation.