# How to Properly Cite Amazon Braket?

Tags: cirq, amazon-braket

This is a fairly basic question, but how does one cite Braket in BibTeX style? A similar question was asked for Cirq in [How to cite cirq in a scientific article?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11881/how-to-cite-cirq-in-a-scientific-article) but I am unable to find a similar page for Amazon's Braket language. They have a GitHub thing set up but I can't find anything like "here is the citation."

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I've upvoted because I think the question is interesting, but I wonder whether this would be more appropriate on Academia StackExchange, something like "How to cite a proprietary project/software?"

Comment: @TristanNemoz (and others) I'm honestly not sure. We often allow questions here that are quite specific to these frameworks, albeit in the context of programming. This one is a bit different, but it seems to me that of any StackExchange site, people here are the more likely to have an answer. Also, the analogous question about cirq was allowed. I gravitate towards leaving this here, but if people think otherwise, please vote to close mentioning the migration as custom reason, and if a consensus is reached we'll move it

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.12390) was coauthored by members of the Braket team, with the BibTeX entry

```
@website{braket,
  author = {{Amazon Web Services}},
  title = {{Amazon Braket}},
  url = {https://aws.amazon.com/braket/},
  year=2020
}
```

so feel free to cite it like this.